# "Set up OneDrive" dialog box keeps appearing every login

Tags: onedrive

Every time I start up my windows 10 Home edition PC, after a few minutes this thing will pop up. [image]

I always have to close it, then go to its tray icon and close it there.

I don't want to use it. How can I stop it from starting up every day?

I use a local win10 account, not connected to online

edit: my task manager

[image]

Comment: @DavidPostill why is this older question marked duplicate when it came before the new one?

Comment: Because the other one has a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click `Start`-> type in `taskmgr`. Once Task Manager is loaded up click on the `Startup` tab. Click on `Microsoft OneDrive` once to highlight it and select `disable` in the lower right hand corner. Once you disable it reboot and it shouldn't start with your system anymore.[image: disableonedrive]

If it is not listed in your startup then I would suggest taking a look at this article: https://techjourney.net/disable-or-uninstall-onedrive-completely-in-windows-10/

Comment: Will try this and update in an hour

Comment: @RegisteredUser Did my answer work?

Comment: onedrive isn't in the list

Comment: @RegisteredUser can you provide a screenshot update? also take a look at what services are starting up.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: The article would not apply to me since i'm running win10 home edition, so no gpedit.msc. sorry for not mentioning

Comment: The article shows how to do it through the registry and command prompt as well for Home users.

Comment: Tested it for a few days. Registry edit worked fine, thank you